# PHP Imap mail answer

Tags: php, email, imap

The beginning of my code looks like that:

```
$hostname = '{**HOST**}';
$username = '**USERNAME**';
$password = '**PASSWORD**';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);



$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

if($emails)
{
    $output = '';

    rsort($emails);

    foreach($emails as $email_number)
    {

        $header=imap_headerinfo($inbox,$email_number);

        $from = $header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;
        $toaddress=$header->toaddress;
        $replyto=$header->reply_to[0]->mailbox."@".$header->reply_to[0]->host;
        $datetime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$header->udate);
        $subject=imap_utf8($header->subject);

        //remove the " from the $toaddress
        $toaddress = str_replace('"','',$toaddress);

        echo '<strong>To:</strong> '.$toaddress.'<br>';
        echo '<strong>From:</strong> '.$from.'<br>';
        echo '<strong>Subject:</strong> '.$subject.'<br>';
                echo '<strong>date:</strong> '.$datetime.'<br>';

        //get message body
        $message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.1));
        if($message == '')
        {
            $message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1));
        }
        echo '<strong>msg:</strong> '.$message.'<br><br>';
    }
}
```

The `$message` variable returns the content inside the message, but if the person **responds** to my email, the previous message sent will be also inside `$message`.

Here is an example of output I get for `$message` :

```
Yes I would love it !


Le vendredi, janvier 18, 2019, 5:49 PM, test <test@xtestx.fr> a écrit :

Bonjour, 
Merci de nous avoir contactés. 

Aimez-vous faire cela ?

Si vous souhaitez d'autres informations, n'hésitez pas à répondre directement à ce mail. 

Cordialement, 
L'équipe.
```

I would like to get only the first line "Yes I would love it !" which is actually the real answer to my email, because all the text below is the previous mail.

Thanks,

Comment: From what I can see, I assume the citation is actually part of the sent email. That's near-to-impossible to strip off, because the citation style can vary depending on the sender's mail client

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but maybe all mail client have <name@client.com> inside the first line that I want to get rid off. Something like a preg match which removes the first line with this then all the other lines

Comment: What happens if I just sent you a message where, among lots of other details, I also give you the mail address of a contact I copied from the VCard. That looked like this: `Some text (even containing line breaks)... Here's the contact: (line break) "Some Name <some.name@example.com>" (line break) ... continuation of my message`? There is no citation. You still would take the part below as a citation using this approach

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```
$message=explode($message, "\n")[0];
```

It should work.

Comment: Hello Jaime, you can **edit** your answer to improve it.

Comment: Hi, if the user sends a message with a line break inside it, it will save only the first line :/ For exemple :
'Hello, how are you \n\n Thanks for answering my question \n\n I liked it a lot'

will save only « Hello, how are you »